# Function works in console but not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple binary to decimal converter page with an option to compare. My binary to decimal function works fine and jQuery can run and display it to the DOM. My compare function works fine in console but doesn't work when called on by a jQuery click function. Console.log works with the exact same numbers outside of the jQuery function, but not inside. Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deniswells59/ekdtk60t/

```
//simple compare function
var result = "";
var assert_equal = function(bin, dec) {
    if(bin === dec){
       return result = ("They are Equal!");
    } else {
      return result = ("They aren't Equal!");
    };
 };

//this works fine as well as .binaryToDecimal(), which I didn't include
$("#convert").click(function(){
   var value = $("#binToConvert").val();
   var valueConverted = value.binaryToDecimal();
   $("#display").html("<span class='results'>"+value+"</span> converts to <span class='results'>"+valueConverted+"</span>");
});

//this ALWAYS displays "They aren't Equal!"; console.log says otherwise
$("#compare").click(function() {
   var binary =$("#binary").val();
   var decimal =$("#decimal").val();
   binary = binary.binaryToDecimal();
   assert_equal(binary, decimal);
   $("#display").html("<span class='results'>"+result+"</span>");
});
```

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle?

Comment: You should also add your binaryToDecimal function and what data you're adding in your input boxes for clarification.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deniswells59/ekdtk60t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the function to the assert_equal as below

```
var assert_equal = function(bin, dec) {
  if(bin.binaryToDecimal() == dec)
    return result = ("They are Equal!");
}
```

Comment: That worked! Do you happen to know why 202 != 202 in the jQuery function though? They were both string types.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure they're the same type. Right now `bin` is a number and `dec` is a string (because jQuery's `.val()` always returns a string, even if the user entered a number). `bin` is a number because your `binaryToDecimal` function returns a number.

Just convert `dec` and `bin` to the same type before you compare them in your `assert_equal` function. Otherwise you can just use `==` if you do not care about type.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var assert_equal = function(bin, dec) {
    if(parseInt(bin) === parseInt(dec)){
    return result = ("They are Equal!");
  } else {
    return result = ("They aren't Equal!");
  };
};
```